# What's wrong with this RenameFile?

Tags: bugs, files-and-directories, windows

**Bug introduced in 5.2 or earlier, persisting through 11.2.0 and fixed in 12.3 or earlier** [CASE:3962020]

<sub>The bug appears on Windows only</sub>

---

I want to rename a `.txt` file.

For example create a file on your Desktop and name it use `TEST.TXT`, now I want to rename it to `test.txt`:

```
RenameFile["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\TEST.TXT",
           "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.txt"]
```

It seems that `RenameFile` does not distinguish the ***UPPER CASE*** from the  ***lower case*** in the file extensions.
So how can I rename this file?

*Ps*: I use *MATLAB* in my homework, but *MATLAB* can only read `*.m` in terms of `*.M` files. So I must rename the `*.M` files. Therefore I use `*.TXT` and `*.txt` to make a example.

Comment: Works like a charm for me on _Linux_.

Comment: I suspect this is an OS problem, since Windows, by default, does not utilize a case-sensitive filesystem, although there are some [exceptions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725747.aspx).

Comment: Your words amuse me...what's meaning of charm in the sentence?

Comment: @user15961 "Works like a charm" is a typical English expression for "it works well"

Comment: @user15961 I'm glad I amused you :P See [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/work+like+a+charm).

Comment: I am very happy to learn Mathematica as well as English at the same time here.*^_^*

Comment: Glad to know there is a workaround, but this ought to be reported to wolfram support.

Comment: @bobthechemist I don't think this is the problem of windows. windows cmd has `ren` function which has no problem rename upper case to lower case. I think this is apparently a bug. Latest 11.2 still has this problem.

Comment: Reported to Wolfram: CASE:3962020.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler alternative:

```
winRenameFile[f1_, f2_] := Module[{}, RenameFile[f1, "pre" <> f1];
  RenameFile["pre" <> f1, f2]]
```

Comment: Crap, that is much simpler.

Comment: Ok! Words like a charm in my computer! Thank you everyone!

Comment: @user15961 Works* :)

Answer (score 0):

i meet the same problem with RenameFile. Somehow when i loop through a folder, it can only rename one file and then pump up with the above error message. It turns out to be, that , the filename you got by FileNames uses single backslash that should be double backslash . So all you need to do is to replace backslash to double backslash. Then it works! Another wired thing is: if you manually copy one filename from the output of FileNames, all the single backslash in that name automatically turns into double backslash. So it seems like when you put such name indirectly into a function, the program fails to make that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I do not reproduce the bug with *Mathematica* versions 12.3.1 and 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64:

[image: screenshot]

As one can see from the screenshot, the file is renamed to "pLoT.png", as expected.

*Mathematica* 8.0.4 on the same machine produces an error message:

[image: screenshot]

Hence the bug was fixed in 12.3 or earlier.