# why CopyFile cannot overwrite existing file?

Tags: programming, files-and-directories

CopyFile return `$Failed` when the file exists on destination.

is there any way to force CopyFile to overwrite the existing one?

the way I use now is DeleteFile and then CopyFile

Comment: From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CopyFile.html?q=CopyFile) for `CopyFile["file1","file2"]`: "`file1` must already exist; `file2` must not."

Comment: So this is a [documentation bug](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1371/18476)?

Comment: i don't think an undocumented option should be considered a "bug". There may be legitimate reasons, especially for a system related function it may not be robustly tested for all system combinations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `OverwriteTarget -> True` option. Alas, this is not specified in the documentation.

```
?? CopyFile
```

gives, among other details,

> Options[CopyFile]={OverwriteTarget->False}

```
CopyFile[ "foo1.txt", "foo2.txt", OverwriteTarget -> True ]
```

does the trick for me.

Comment: (+1) very very nice. it is great to see you answer one on my equations again :)

Comment: by the way, this option is not available in older version of MM. it is only in V10.

Comment: Be careful using this option with RenameFile[], for me it resulted in loss of data. I wanted to do a batch rename changing the file extension to lower case. It worked for some files but inexplicably got $Failed for others. Maybe its the bug mentioned here? : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60990/whats-wrong-with-this-renamefile. When I added the OverwriteTarget->True option it deleted the source file and did not rename it. I confirmed the file was deleted by exhaustive search on all hard drives with a programmer's tool and then recovered the file with Recuva.